# conversion de apuntadores (*) y funciones

Tags: c, funciones, punteros

Tengo dudas sobre lo que significa el operador `tipo (*)`. (tipo = int, char ..etc). Entiendo que es algo así como convertir a apuntador tal cosa.

Este ejemplo es sacado del libro de programación en C de Ritchie, la idea es poder pasarle una de 2 funciones cualquiera a una función de ordenamiento, para que esta ordene cierta cantidad de líneas de caracteres por orden numérico o lexicográfico. Una función compara numéricamente (numcmp)y la otra lexicográficamente (strcmp).

Ambas tienen la forma `int funcion (char*,char*)`, en la declaración de la función de ordenarLineas el argumento en donde se entrega la función se declara como `int( * funcion)(void*,void*)` para entregarle cuando se llame más adelante a está función alguna de las otras funciones (numcmp y strcmp) como argumento.

¿Que es lo que hace exactamente la línea de `(int (*) (void*, void*))`?, Creo que es una especie de casting a la función que se le entrega (strcmp o numcmp) pero no encontrado mucha información sobre el tema, ¿alguien podría explicarme o indicarme algún lugar donde pueda buscar más información?

```
int numerico = 0;

if ((cantLineas = leerLineas(apuntlineas, CANTLINEAS)) >=  0){
         ordenarLineas((void *)apuntlineas, 0, cantLineas - 1,
           (int (*) (void*,void*)) (numerico ? numcmp : strcmp));
         escribirLineas(apuntlineas, cantLineas);
  }
```

Comment: Vale gracias, si es principalmente el concepto

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ¿Que es lo que hace exactamente la línea de (int (*) (void*, void*))?

Es una conversión de un puntero a función:

```
(int (*) (void*, void*))
 ~~~ ~~~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  1   2       3
```

Donde:

1. Tipo de retorno de la función
2. Esta es la forma de indicar los punteros a función (en este caso un puntero a función)
3. Los parámetros de la función.

Lo que hace es, básicamente, forzar a que una función de tipo

```
int (*) (char*, char*)
```

Se llame como si su tipado fuese el siguiente:

```
int (*) (void*, void*)
```

Hay que destacar que la operación de conversión de punteros hay que hacerla con mucho cuidado, ya que puedes obtener toda suerte de comportamientos inesperados, sobretodo si juegas con diferentes arquitecturas.

Comment: pero al mismo tiempo que convierte el tipo de los argumentos, tambien crea un apuntador a la funcion, porque como tal la funcion no tiene asignada ningun apuntador, o el nombre de las funciones tambien sirve como direccion igual que el nombre de los arreglos?, sabes donde puedo encontrar informacion algo mas detallada sobre la conversion de tipos para apuntadores? Gracias.

Comment: @edwinvargas Es que la función no necesita ningún apuntador. A ver, si tu tienes una función puedes obtener un puntero a la misma ese puntero puedes tratarlo como cualquier otra variable de tu código. El nombre de las funciones solo te sirve a tí. El programa se ejecuta en binario y su representación más cercana es ensamblador... ahí no hay funciones con nombres sino solamente instrucciones. El nombre de los arreglos tampoco sirve como dirección. Deberías repasar el tema de los punteros, ya que al fin y al cabo lo que estás tratando en esta pregunta son, simple y llanamente, punteros

Answer (score 3):

> ¿Que es lo que hace exactamente la línea de `(int (*) (void*, void*))`?

El código es bastante confuso, la parte que resaltas es un puntero anónimo a una función que devuelve `int` y recibe dos punteros a `void`:

```
//   El puntero no tiene nombre
//      |
//      v
   int (*) (void*, void*)
//  |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~^ <--- Función
//  |         |      |
//  |         \______\________ Recibe dos punteros void (void *)
//  \_________________________ Devuelve un entero (int)
```

> Creo que es una especie de casting a la función que se le entrega (strcmp o numcmp)

Eso parece, en [c](/questions/tagged/c) una conversión de tipos se da al poner entre paréntesis un tipo antes que un valor:

```
tipo convertido = (tipo)valor;
```

Así que `int (*) (void*, void*)` es efectivamente una conversión de la expresión `(numerico ? numcmp : strcmp)` a función que devuelve un entero y recibe dos punteros a `void`, esta conversión se pasa como cuarto parámetro a la función `ordenarLineas`.

No conozco la función `numcmp`, pero la función [`strcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) no recibe dos punteros a void<strike>, así que a priori ese cast es incorrecto y tiene la posibilidad de generar errores en tiempo de ejecución, errores que se detectarían en tiempo de compilación si los tipos fuesen correctos</strike>, al ocultar los tipos tras un puntero a `void` eliminamos algunas alarmas que pueden ayudar a encontrar errores en tiempo de compilación:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int recibe_float(float *f) { printf("%s = %f\n", __FUNCTION__, *f); }
int recibe_char(char *c) { printf("%s = %c\n", __FUNCTION__, *c); }

int main(void)
{
    char c = 'c';
    float f = 42.f;

    int(*funcion_f)(void*) = (int(*)(void*))recibe_float;
    int(*funcion_c)(void*) = (int(*)(void*))recibe_char;

    recibe_float(&c); // alarma: asignación desde un puntero de tipo incompatible
    recibe_char(&f);  // alarma: asignación desde un puntero de tipo incompatible

    funcion_f(&c); // ¡Ninguna alarma!
    funcion_c(&f); // ¡Ninguna alarma!

    return 0;
}
```

En el código de ejemplo anterior, vemos que si a las funciones `recibe_float` y `recibe_char` se les pasan punteros incorrectos, el compilador avisa con una alarma. Pero si se le hace conversión a la función para que reciba un puntero a `void`, la alarma desaparece.

Al ejecutar el código vemos que la salida es completamente incorrecta:

> ```
> recibe_float = 0.000000
> recibe_char = 
> recibe_float = 0.000000
> recibe_char =
> ```

La función `recibe_float` no recibió un `float` con valor cero si no un carácter con valor `'c'`, así mismo la función `recibe_char` no recibió un `char` con valor no imprimible si no un número en coma flotante con valor `42.f`. Estos fallos son inocuos en un programa así, pero en un programa más complejo podrían ser la puerta de entrada a errores muy difíciles de detectar que habrían sido evidentes de haber usado las conversiones correctas.

Comment: *No conozco la función numcmp, pero la función strcmp no recibe dos punteros a void, así que a priori ese cast es incorrecto...* El casting que hizo el OP es correcto. Ese casting se lo hace para usar la función `strcmp` como argumento y esto ahorra en tener que definir una función de comparación (usando esta firma: `(void*, void*)`) y retornar lo que devuelva `strcmp`. Aquí en la documentación dan un [ejemplo](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/bsearch/) sobre eso.

Comment: No me puedo creer semejante despreocupación con los tipos en las propias librerías de C.